# How to set focus on an element in Elm?

Tags: html, elm

How can I set the focus on a Html element in Elm? I tried to set the autofocus attribute on the element and it only sets the focus on the page load.

Answer (score 56, accepted):

The `focus` function in the [elm-lang/dom](http://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm-lang/dom/latest/Dom#focus) package is used to set focus with a `Task` (without using any `port`s or JavaScript).

Internally it uses [`requestAnimationFrame`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/requestAnimationFrame) to ensure any new DOM updates are rendered before it tries to find the DOM node to focus on.

An example use:

```elm
type Msg
    = FocusOn String
    | FocusResult (Result Dom.Error ())

update : Msg -> Model -> ( Model, Cmd Msg )
update msg model =
    case msg of
        FocusOn id ->
            ( model, Dom.focus id |> Task.attempt FocusResult )

        FocusResult result ->
            -- handle success or failure here
            case result of
                Err (Dom.NotFound id) ->
                    -- unable to find dom 'id'
                Ok () ->
                    -- successfully focus the dom
```

[Full example on Ellie](https://embed.ellie-app.com/vsvWQMXjQqa1/0)

Comment: Note, this *does* work, but I found it can silently fail at unexpected times if the element is added dynamically.

Comment: Do you have an example where this fails?

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't have a reproducible example right now. I'll post back if I find another. Overall, this is definitely the right way of doing it, so my comment should be ignored until I can find a specific case :)

Comment: "setting focus can silently fail if the element is invisible." http://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm-lang/dom/latest/Dom#focus

Comment: If using Elm 0.19, this package is now part of [elm/browser](https://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm/browser/latest/Browser-Dom).

Answer (score 10):

A workaround for this is to use [Mutation Observers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver). Insert this JavaScript either in your main HTML page or in the main view of your Elm code:

```js
var observer = new MutationObserver(function(mutations) {
  mutations.forEach(function(mutation) {
    handleAutofocus(mutation.addedNodes);
  });
});
var target = document.querySelector('body > div');
var config = { childList: true, subtree: true };
observer.observe(target, config);

function handleAutofocus(nodeList) {
  for (var i = 0; i < nodeList.length; i++) {
    var node = nodeList[i];
    if (node instanceof Element && node.hasAttribute('data-autofocus')) {
      node.focus();
      break;
    } else {
      handleAutofocus(node.childNodes);
    }
  }
}
```

Then create HTML elements by including `Html.Attributes.attribute "data-autofocus" ""`.

Answer (score 5):

With elm/html 0.19 you can set the [`Html.Attrbutes autofocus`](https://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm/html/1.0.0/Html-Attributes#autofocus) to `True`

```
input [ onInput Code, autofocus True ] []
```

Comment: This doesn't appear to work reliably, I opened an issue [here](https://github.com/elm/html/issues/186).

Comment: Yes the `Dom.focus id |> Task.attempt FocusResult` is more reliable

Comment: This also needs `import Browser.Dom` in the file, example here https://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm/core/latest/Task#attempt

Answer (score 4):

I spent quite a bit of time exploring this recently. Unfortunately, I don't think it is possible with the existing `elm-html` library. However, I came up with a hack that utilizes css animations to trigger an event and embed that in pure js.

Here is my hack in Elm using a `script` node and a `style` node. It is very ugly in my opinion.

```
import Html exposing (div, button, text, input, node)
import Html.Events exposing (onClick)
import Html.Attributes exposing (type', class)
import StartApp.Simple

main =
  StartApp.Simple.start { model = model, view = view, update = update }

model = []

view address model =
  -- View now starts with a <style> and <script> (hacky)
  (node "style" [] [ Html.text style ]) ::
  (node "script" [] [Html.text script ]) ::
  (button [ onClick address AddInput ] [ text "Add Input" ]) ::
  model |>
  div []    

type Action = AddInput 

update action model =
  case action of
    AddInput -> (Html.p [] [input [type' "text", class "focus"] []]) :: model

-- Use pure string css (hacky)

style = """
.focus {
  animation-name: set-focus;
  animation-duration: 0.001s;
  -webkit-animation-name: set-focus;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 0.001s;
}
@-webkit-keyframes set-focus {
    0%   {color: #fff}
}
@keyframes set-focus {
    0%   {color: #fff}
}
"""

-- Cheating by embedding pure javascript... (hacky)

script = """
var insertListener = function(event){
 if (event.animationName == "set-focus") {
   event.target.focus();
 }               
}
document.addEventListener("animationstart", insertListener, false); // standard + firefox
document.addEventListener("MSAnimationStart", insertListener, false); // IE
document.addEventListener("webkitAnimationStart", insertListener, false); // Chrome + Safari
"""
```

Answer (score 3):

In Elm 0.19, use [`Browser.Dom.focus`](https://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm/browser/latest/Browser-Dom#focus):

```
import Browser.Dom as Dom
import Task

type Msg
    = NoOp

focusSearchBox : Cmd Msg
focusSearchBox =
    Task.attempt (\_ -> NoOp) (Dom.focus "search-box")
```

You can choose to ignore if focusing fails like above or do something by triggering an update message.

Answer (score 1):

Elm 0.19's [`Browser.Dom.focus`](https://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm/browser/latest/Browser-Dom#focus) is the modern solution

```
import Browser.Dom as Dom
import Task

type Msg
    = NoOp
    | Focus String

focusElement : String -> Cmd Msg
focusElement htmlId =
    Task.attempt (\_ -> NoOp) (Dom.focus htmlId)


update : Msg -> Model -> (Model, Cmd Msg)
update msg =
    case msg of
        Focus htmlId ->
            ( model, focusElement htmlId )
        NoOp ->
            ( model, Cmd.none )
```